# How to replace ' in a String in java?

Tags: java

```
String str="India's";
str.replaceAll("'", "");
```

The above code in my opinion should replace all inverted single commas with nothing in the string.

But the in the output nothing changes.

Can anyone figure out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Assign the returned result back to `str` (or another variable).

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable, assign it to the same reference

```
str = str.replaceAll("'", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

String is an immutable class, any change to an object of this class will result in a new object created. Method `replaceAll` is returning the updated String object. so you should do something like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("'","");
```